# How can i hide the youtube control watchlater in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my `iframe` that I load in my HTML:

```
<iframe id="userGuideVideo" width="520" height="300" style="margin-left: 80px;margin-top: 7px;" src="about:blank"></iframe>
```

```js
$('#userGuideVideo').attr('src','https://URL?enablejsapi=1');
```

Comment: thanks @Rory McCrossan

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you have gotten your answer yet or not.

But what you could do is, use the embed parameters for example:

```
<iframe id="userGuideVideo" width="520" height="300" style="margin-left: 80px;margin-top: 7px;" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/YCDbiAhxJ4M?autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&ps=docs"></iframe>
```

There are all sort of items you are able to hide.

You can find the full list at: 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of this use modestbranding=1 is used for to hide the youtube control Watchlater and rel=0 is used to hide the share control of youtube in iframe

eg.

$('#optionsPlayVideo').attr('src','https://www.youtube.com/embed/tQ0DR9byov0?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&autohide=1&showinfo=0&modestbranding=1');

where my iframe is

```
<iframe id="optionsPlayVideo" width="520" height="348" style="margin-left: 80px;margin-top: 7px;" src="about:blank"></iframe>
```

this solution works for me Thanks